# Advanced product filtering with Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

My Product structure is

```
product2: {
    allAttributes: {
        Color: ['black', 'silver'],
        model: ["hero7"],
        accessories: ["full travel kit", "2 batteries", "2 batteries + charger"],
        brand: ["GoPro"]
    }
    category: ["camping"]
    depositAmount: 1500
    depositAmountTooltip: "Fully refundable security for this product."
    displayrent: 650
    expressDeliveryCharge: 200
    id: "Ur89kjsllljVdQ8MM"
    inventory: 5
    keywords: (6)["Camping", "Outdoor", "Camera", "Electronic", "Gopro", "Action Cameras"]
    longDescription: "longdescription"
    name: "Gopro Hero 7 Black"
    pictures: (3)[{
        …}, {
        …}, {
        …}]
    rank: 4501
    subCategory: (6)["camping", "outdoor", "camera", "electronic", "gopro", "actioncamera"]
}

product1: {
    allAttributes: {
        Color: ['black', 'silver'],
        model: ["hero8"],
        accessories: ["full travel kit", "2 batteries", "2 batteries + charger"],
        brand: ["GoPro"]
    }
    category: ["camping"]
    depositAmount: 2000
    depositAmountTooltip: "Fully refundable security for this product."
    displayrent: 750
    expressDeliveryCharge: 200
    id: "Ur89kfksj1mVdQ8MM"
    inventory: 5
    keywords: (6)["Camping", "Outdoor", "Camera", "Electronic", "Gopro", "Action Cameras"]
    longDescription: "longdescription"
    name: "Gopro Hero 8 Black"
    pictures: (3)[{
        …}, {
        …}, {
        …}]
    rank: 4500
    subCategory: (6)["camping", "outdoor", "camera", "electronic", "gopro", "actioncamera"]
}
```

I'm querying it like,

```
const {category, subCategory, color, brand } = req.query;
       AllProductModel.where('category', '==', category)
      .where('subCategory', 'array-contains-any', subCategory)
      .get()
```

Now, it's not possible for me to query based on `color`(array from req.query) and `brand`(array from req.query) attributes
How do I query products like this on Cloud Firestore based on `allAttributes` selected from client side. I do not want to do it on client app.

I'm using "ReactJS" and "NodeJS, Express".

Comment: Did you try something already? If not, I recommend starting with https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries. If you did that already, please edit your question to include the [minimum code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey, Thanks for the help. I have gone through the query documentation on firestore.

One workaround I have thought is to load let's say 3000-4000 documents on my server and then filter them there. Filtered documents then to be sent to my frontend. Can this be possible or how much load it's going to be place on my server?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Which Database would you recommend if not firestore? I'm currently using GAE to deploy my app (frontend and backend separately) and I'm planning to switch to GCP cloud functions.

Answer (score 1):

If `product1` and `product2` are each a document in a collection (say `products`), then you can select for example all products that are available in silver with:

```
let productsRef = firebase.firestore().collection('products');
productsRef.where("allAtributes.Color", "array-contains", "silver")
```

The above query uses an [`array-contains` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

---

You can also select all products that are available in either silver or black with:

```
productsRef.where("allAtributes.Color", "array-contains-any", ["silver", "black"])
```

This so-called [`array-contains-any`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) clause can:

> use the `array-contains-any` operator to combine up to 10 `array-contains` clauses on the same field with a logical OR.

---

You can do the above query clauses on any of the fields in `allAttributes`. But you can only do this clause on one field. From the [documentation on query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations):

> You can use only one `in` or `array-contains-any` clause per query. You can't use both `in` and `array-contains-any` in the same query.

So you can query for all products that are available in silver or black, and you can query for all products from GoPro, but you can't query for app GoPro products that are available in silver or black.

If you'd store the brand as a single-value field like this:

```
    "allAttributes": {
        ...
        brand: "GoPro"
    }
```

With the above structure you *can* query like this:

```
productsRef
  .where("allAtributes.brand", "==", "GoPro")
  .where("allAtributes.Color", "array-contains-any", ["silver", "black"])
```

To get all GoPro products that are available in silver or black, but of course at that point each product can only be of a single brand.

---

If your use-case absolutely requires the types of queries that aren't possible on Firestore, consider combining or replacing Firestore with another database.